# Create a function in python, which will impute mean OR median values in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, mean, median

I have a dataframe

```
data = {'Age':[18, np.nan, 17, 14, 15, np.nan, 17, 17]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

I would like to write a solution, which would allow to impute either mean or median,
using

```
df = df.fillna 
df = df.fillna(df.median())
```

Desired output for mean

```
data = {'Age':[18, 16.3, 17, 14, 15, 16.3, 17, 17]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

Desired output for median

```
data = {'Age':[18, 17, 17, 14, 15, 17, 17, 17]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function:

```
def f(df, func):
    if func in ['mean','median']:
        return df.fillna(df.agg(func))
    else:
        raise Exception("Wrong function, use only 'mean' or 'median'")
```

If need `mean` use:

```
df = f(df, 'mean')
```

If need `median` use:

```
df = f(df, 'median')
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is it a function? :)

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - yes, by `df.replace('nan', np.nan)`

Comment: My point - I want to have a choice either to impute means or medians, applying a function to the column.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - Not sure if understand, maybe probble broken code `df = df.fillna ` is necessary remove?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - added to answer.

Comment: Okay, you print both, but I want to select the imputation method. If I want to impute means, it gives output with means. If medians - with medians

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 1):

First parse `'nan'` as a `float`:

```
df = df.astype(float)
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
print (df)
```

Output:

```
         Age
0  18.000000
1  16.333333
2  17.000000
3  14.000000
4  15.000000
5  16.333333
6  17.000000
7  17.000000
```

For function:

```
def f(df, func):
    return df.fillna([df.mean(), df.median()][func == 'mean'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to put it into a function where I will impute with means or medians?

Comment: Voted, but accepted the first answer chronologically :)

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker Ah, great!

Answer (score 1):

A universal solution for all columns at once

```py
data = {'Age':[18, 'nan', 17, 14, 15, 'nan', 17, 17]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df = df.astype('float')

def foo(s, func):
    val = func(s)
    return s.fillna(val)

df.apply(foo, args=(np.mean,))
```

or

```py
df.apply(foo, args=(np.median,))
```

or

```py
df.apply(foo, args(custom_function,))
```